# Perform a Progress Indicator in a background task javafx

Tags: java, multithreading, javafx, progress-indicator

During the execution of the task the progress indicator runs smoothly , but when the task ends the progress indicator continues to turn . I wish the end of this task the progress indicator stops. Here is my code

```
nextButton.setDisable(true);
task = createWorker();          
progressInd.progressProperty().bind(task.progressProperty());
th = new Thread(task);          
th.start();
```

and there is my task.

```
public Task createWorker() {
    return new Task() {
        @Override
        protected Object call() throws Exception {
            list = new LinkedList<BufferedImage>();
            list = vX.getFrame(path.getText());
            System.out.println(list.size());
            vX.getCorruptedImage((LinkedList<BufferedImage>) list);
            progressInd.progressProperty().unbind();
            progressInd.setProgress(task.getProgress());
            nextButton.setDisable(false);
            return output;
        }
    };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot change the UI from the background thread, so the lines

```
progressInd.progressProperty().unbind();
progressInd.setProgress(task.getProgress());
nextButton.setDisable(false);
```

should not be executed in your `call()` method.

Instead, you should do

```
nextButton.setDisable(true);
task = createWorker();          
progressInd.progressProperty().bind(task.progressProperty());
task.setOnSucceeded(e -> {
    progressInd.progressProperty().unbind();
    progressInd.setProgress(1); // mark as complete...
    nextButton.setDisable(false);
});
// always good practice to (at a minimum) log exceptions if they occur:
task.setOnFailed(e -> task.getException().printStackTrace());
th = new Thread(task);          
th.start();
```

Comment: Then you are not reaching the `onSucceeded` handler, probably because you are getting an exception. See update to see how to figure out what is going wrong.